# Method update C # connection error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I made a method called update that updates the data in the database,Which calls the method named GetUpdateCommand that has the method with the database update command,I created a variable cn that receives the connection string with bank,But when trying to open the connection and surround it with a try catch, it does not find the variable cn with the connection,
Because you can not find the variable

```
public SqlCommand GetUpdateCommand()
    {

        //faz o for em que vai percorrer, traga somente os campos com o atributo customizado do tipo DataObjectFieldAttribute
        SqlCommand retorno = new SqlCommand();
        retorno.CommandText = "Update  {0}  set {1} where {2}";

        String tabela = typeof(T).Name;
        String campos = "";
        String chave = "";
        foreach (PropertyInfo pro in typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataObjectFieldAttribute)) != null))
        {
            DataObjectFieldAttribute att = (DataObjectFieldAttribute)pro.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DataObjectFieldAttribute));

            if (att.PrimaryKey==true)//defini a chave primaria no DataObjectField na classe cliente colocando true
            {
                chave= pro.Name + "=@" + pro.Name;//pega a chava a chave primaria e adc no parametro
                retorno.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pro.Name, pro.GetValue(this));//adicona os parametros
            }
            else
            {
                campos += pro.Name + "=@" + pro.Name + ",";
                retorno.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + pro.Name, pro.GetValue(this));
            }


        }
        //retorna com os parametros de acordo com o comando sql do uopdate.
        retorno.CommandText = String.Format(retorno.CommandText, tabela, campos,chave);

        return retorno;


    }

 public void atualizar()
    {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|C:\Users\Antonio Viana\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Loja\Eccomerce\App_Data\dados.mdf;Integrated Security=True")) ;
        {

            SqlCommand cm = this.GetUpdateCommand();

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `) ;` closes the scope behind `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the scope of `using` right behind the object initialization by closing the `using` with `;`.

So this line:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...)) ;
```

should look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...))
```

Comment: Nice spot there @jAC

Comment: Worked thank you brother